# Vector template class used in BST template class

Tags: c++, templates

How to deal with such task. I implemented BST template class which is capable to do operations on simple types like `int`, `float` etc. Now I want to implement another template class `Vector` and add different functionality for this type in BST template class because every comparison in case of `Vector` type compare Vector length not just value (in these case two values).

### bst.h

```
#ifndef BSTTREE_BST_H
#define BSTTREE_BST_H

template <class T> class bst {
   struct node {
       T d;
       node *l, *r;
    };
    node* root;
public:
    bst();
    ~bst();
    void freeMemory(node* bstNode);
    void insert(T x); 
    void show(); 
    void show(node* bstNode);
    int count(node* bstNode);
    node* search(T x);
    node* search(node* bstNode, T x);
    bool rmv(T x); 
};

#include "bst.cpp"
#endif //BSTTREE_BST_H
```

### bst.cpp

```
#ifndef BSTTREE_BST_CPP
#define BSTTREE_BST_CPP

#include "bst.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
bst<T>::bst() {}

template <class T>
bst<T>::~bst() {}

template <class T>
void bst<T>::freeMemory(bst::node *node) {}

template <class T>
void bst<T>::insert(T x){}

template <class T>
void bst<T>::show() {}

template <class T>
void bst<T>::show(node* root) {}

template <class T>
int bst<T>::count(node* root) {}

template <class T>
typename bst<T>::node* bst<T>::search(T x) {}

template <class T>
typename bst<T>::node* bst<T>::search(node* root, T x) {}

template <class T>
node* bst<T>::rmv(int value, node *parent) {}

#endif //BSTTREE_BST_CPP
```

I didn't implement methods inner body, because it works just fine and it isn't the task. I know some things in this code are done wrong but I had to follow some rules which in my opinion aren't very clever, but it isn't the point.

I thought about making another template Class `vector` in .h/.cpp files and include header to `Vector` class in bst.cpp and write there additional functionality for only `Vector` class template. 
Is it a good idea? Or there is better way to do it (without changing my code very much if it is possible). How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

C++ supports [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), this means that if you stick to using a specific comparison operator, eg `*(root->l) < *(root->r)` this will work correctly with primitive types as `int`, `float`, etc.

At the same time you can define your custom

```
bool Vector::operator<(const Vector& other) const { return this->length() < other.length(); }
```

So that the BST template class will correctly invoke your specified overloaded method when comparing `Vector` instances.

Comment: Ok, but what when I will want to insert a `Vector` object when every methods in bst template are designed to take signel value argument? I am bit confused...

Comment: @Saris Whatever operations on `T` your `bst<T>` uses, need to be implemented in `Vector`. Most probably this is `<` (compare) and `=` (assign). Having ensured such operations exist, `bst<Vector>` *just works*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding functionalities for a specific `vector` class, you can try creating an overloaded function where you compare the 2 values, and add a third argument to that function, which would be a function pointer, which you can define in your `vector` class.

Example ::

```
void func1(T v1, T v2, (bool) (*compare) (T, T));
```

(`T` is the template type)

And you can create this `compare` function, which might not only compare the lengths but also someother properties, depending upon the situation, and in `func1` use the results returned by `compare`.

More about function pointers [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)